# Would chocolate liqueur cherries be allowed through Australian customs?

Tags: australia, food-and-drink

If the liqueur cherries have a stem and seeds will they be allowed into Australia through Australian customs?

Comment: Yes, you can bring it. But how many? If its a large amount, you must consider the alcohol importation rules and taxes.

Answer (score 3):

Probably yes, but **you must declare it**.

Commercially processed and packaged foods that have low risk of carrying pests or pathogens can generally be brought into Australia.

However, if in doubt, you should declare it.  The worst thing that can happen is that it will be confiscated.  If you do not declare and get caught, you may be subject to heavy penalties, including [an appearance on a TV show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Security:_Australia%27s_Front_Line).